# Geting list of associated products of group product

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, grouped-products, associated-products

I'm struggling to get a list of associated products from `addtocart.phtml`.

I've already tried all options from this and other forums but nothing is working as I wish.

I've got this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
            }
```

But it seems is always pulling associated products only form first group product in catalog doesn't matter which group product currently viewing.

This probably mean I have to force it to get products for particular `id` by using `$_product->getId()` but I don't know how to do it as it's my first week with magento at all.

I will appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign all product to one variable **$associatedProducts**, you should use array instead of it.
Try to get them in such way

```
$associatedProducts = array();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $associatedProducts[] = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
}
```

To check result use next code:

```
foreach ($associatedProducts as $singleProduct) {
    foreach ($singleProduct as $product) {
       echo $product->getName().'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was silly to not see that `$associatedProducts` is overwriten every time.
So I got now array with every single associated products from catalog but still can't determinate to show just for one group product.

Comment: You can load product directly by Id or another attribute, for example, by id:**bold**$associatedProducts = array();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(149);
$associatedProducts[] = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
foreach ($associatedProducts as $singleProduct) {
    foreach ($singleProduct as $product) {
       echo $product->getName().'<br/>';
    }
}**bold**

Comment: Thank you @olkuznw again. I couldn't make your option working however find solution that do exactly what I was expected 

`$_associatedProducts = array();
                        $_associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);
                    foreach ($_associatedProducts as $product) {
                            echo $product->getName()." - £".$product->getPrice().'"<br/>";}`